# How to Check Playback Time of Audioplayer increases by 2 seconds

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios6, avaudioplayer, nstimer

I m trying to write a loop to check that whenever audio player.currenttime increases by 2 seconds then it should execute update view method

```
- (void)myTimerMethod{

 NSLog(@"myTimerMethod is Called");

myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                           target:self
                                         selector:@selector(checkPlaybackTime:)
                                         userInfo:nil
                                          repeats:YES];

  }


- (void)checkPlaybackTime:(NSTimer *)theTimer
  {
    float seconds =  audioplayer.currenttime;

    NSLog(@"Cur: %f",audioPlayer.currentTime ); 

    if (seconds = seconds + 2){

    [self update view];
}

 - (void)UpdateView{



if  (index < [textArray count])
 {
     self.textView.text = [self.textArray objectAtIndex:index];
   self.imageView.image = [self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:index];
   index++;
}else{

    index = 0;


   }
 }
```

what is the correct way to write if audio player.currenttimer increases by 2 seconds then do this.

NSLog for current time always shows 0.00. Why is that. It should increase as the audioplayer is playing.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i understood from your given explanation that you want to increment the time-interval something like this

```
Timer calls after 0.55
Timer calls after 0.60
Timer calls after 0.65
Timer calls after 0.70
```

& so on.

If that is what you are looking to do. Then i think you can do this way that by changing repeats:YES to repeats:NO so that the timer doesn't repeat, and then in onTimer, just start a new timer with a longer interval.

You need a variable to hold your interval so that you can make it a bit longer each time through onTimer.

Also, you probably don't need to retain the timer anymore, as it will only fire once, and when it does, you'll get a new timer.

```
float gap = 0.50;

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:gap target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

-(void) onTimer {
gap = gap + .05;
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:gap target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

First, try using your float "seconds" in your NSLog rather than the current time.

```
NSLog(@"Cur: %f", seconds);
```

current time is not a float, it's an NSTimer object so you would have to use %@ in your NSLog text so

```
NSLog(@"Cur: %@",audioPlayer.currentTime );
```

Should work as well.

Assuming your audioPlayer is set up correctly, if you're looking for when the timer is at 2 seconds, your if statement will be

```
if(seconds == 2){
    [self update view];
}
```

if you're looking for each time the timer hits an even number, i.e. 2, 4, 6, etc. your if statement will be

```
if(seconds % 2 == 0){
    [self update view];
}
```

The % in an if statement is the modulo sign: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html

Also, your current if statement is assigning rather than checking the seconds variable. To check it, you need == not =. However, your current if statement will never be true since you're checking a variable by itself + 2. To put this another way, if seconds equals 2, your if statement is asking if 2 == (2+2) or if it it is 4, it's asking if 2 == (4+2). This statement cannot validate as true.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply in detail. Appreciate it.